# Android Vitamio Mediaplayer error (1, -1) when using a servers Public IP

Tags: java, android, vitamio

I'm having a strange problem with my android app. I have a local DVR (stream server), and made an app to get live stream from it using Vitamio Library.

```
public class LiveStreamingActivity extends Activity
{
    private static VideoView mVideoView;
    private ProgressDialog prodlg;
    private static String path;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        if (!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
            return;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_stream);

        path="rtsp://user:pass@address:port/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0";

        prodlg=new ProgressDialog(this);
        prodlg.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        prodlg.setMessage("Ju lutem prisni...");
        prodlg.show();

        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vitamio_videoView);

        mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
        mVideoView.setVideoQuality(MediaPlayer.VIDEOQUALITY_HIGH);
        mVideoView.setBufferSize(4096);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.start();
        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
            {
                prodlg.dismiss();
                mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
            }
        });
        mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)
            {
                Log.d("ERROR What", String.valueOf(what));
                Log.d("ERROR Extra", String.valueOf(extra));
                return false;
            }
        });
        mVideoView.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)
            {
                Log.d("INFO What", String.valueOf(what));
                Log.d("INFO Extra", String.valueOf(extra));
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have all the required permissions in manifest.

Now when I try the above code using the servers private IP, it works perfectly fine.When I use the servers public IP however, it fails, giving error (1, -1), saying "Sorry, this video cannot be played."
Also the server can be accessed remotely, tried other IP cam streaming apps, as well as VLC player, and it works just fine. With the exception of VLC 
From what I've seen, only my app is unable to open it remotely. Why is that?

I tried opening other streams from the internet, and they work fine.

logcat also shows:

> [rtsp @ 0x6125e020] method PAUSE failed: 455 Method Not Valid in This
>   State E/Vitamio[4.2.1][Player]: av_find_stream_info: Operation not
>   permitted : -1

I can't figure out if the problem is with the app or network...
If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It could be something as simple as you using the same WiFi as the DVR. You mentioned

`using the servers private IP, it works perfectly fine`

All if not most DVR can't be viewed using public IP under the same WiFi on Android/iOS